# Using the covariance matrix for PCA() in package FactoMineR

Tags: pca

From what I can tell, there's no option to specify a covariance (instead of a corr matrix) in PCA() in package FactoMineR.

Any comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PCA(dd2_pcdat, **scale.unit=FALSE)**

Comment: I received a response from the author stating this was the answer, thanks.